# Rails.root vs directory path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have application where I use SoX to convert audio files, code for same is

```
system "sox public/sound/recording.wav  public/sound/recording.mp3"
```

This works perfectly fine on my dev machine but not on test server. Also when I run this code in rails console it works on test server well.
Later on I changed the code to below

```
file1 = Rails.root.join("public/sound/recording.wav")
file2 = Rails.root.join("public/sound/recording.mp3")
system "sox #{file1} #{file2}"
```

This worked on server. So I have 2 questions

1. Why earlier code worked on dev machine but not on test server?
2. Also why earlier code worked when called from rails console?

Comment: pass `pwd` into the system call and check the lookup path

Comment: It might be a permissions problem. Does the account that the web server runs under have write access to public/sound

Comment: @DaveSexton in that case I guess Rails.root also should have not worked.

Comment: Not so - because Rails.root is reading a path not writing a file. Does the web server account have write access. If you change the permissions on the directory so that everyone has access, does it then work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a permissions problem. Does the account that the web server runs under have write access to public/sound. This would explain why worked in Rails console because you would have been logged in as you and I assume that would also be the account that created the directories.